# How can I make Solaris' Fault Manager forget about an improperly removed ZFS pool?

Tags: zfs, solaris

On a Solaris 11.4 system I had a ZFS pool occupying three drives.  While the system was powered off, these three drives were physically removed, but neither `zpool export` nor `zpool destroy` had been executed, so in principle the system expected the pool to still exist.  This pool is unwanted.

Now, each time I log in, I am confronted with a message:

```
NOTE: system has 3 active faults; run 'fmadm list' for details.
```

When I do that I get many pages of information about the removed disks, with severity `Major`, message IDs of `ZFS-8000-CS` and `ZFS-8000-PE`, Problem Status of `isolated`, Problem class of `fault.fs.zfs.pool` and `fault.fs.zfs.no_replicas`, Status `faulted and taken out of service`, and FRU Status of `faulty/not present`.

This in of itself makes sense, but one confusing aspect is that, while Fault Manager is aware of the "problem," ZFS is not.  ZFS seems to have no concept at all of the missing pool.  When I run `zpool list` I see only the `rpool` (there aren't any other pools).  Same with `zpool status` and `zdb`; both list only the healthy `rpool`, give no errors, faults, or degradation, and make no mention at all of the faulted pool.  If I try `zpool status badpool`, I get:

```
cannot open 'badpool': no such pool
```

Being that I don't want this pool, I have tried `zpool destroy badpool`, but this also gets:

```
cannot open 'badpool': no such pool
```

`-f` doesn't help, it predictably issues the same message.

I don't know what got the system into this state where ZFS has no concept of the pool while Fault Manager is still complaining about it.  It's possible someone may have already executed ZFS commands to destroy it after it was disconnected.

I have skimmed through the man page for `fmadm` and "Managing Faults, Defects, and Alerts in Oracle® Solaris 11.4" but the interface seems to have a gaping hole: it expects you to "repair", "replace", or "acquit" devices, but there is no mention whatsoever as to what to do *if you do not want the device or the service it provides any more.*

So my questions are:

1. **Why might Fault Manager still remember a pool ZFS seems to have forgotten about?**  And,
2. **How can I make Fault Manager forget about it?**

The output of `zpool status`, unremarkable apart from the omission of the missing pool, is:

```
  pool: rpool
    id: 3268360325047915522
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 54s with 0 errors on Tue Sep 19 20:05:51 2023
config:

    NAME      STATE      READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool     ONLINE        0     0     0
      c2t0d0  ONLINE        0     0     0
errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: First of all, this question misses the `zpool status` output.

Comment: @drookie  Sorry, meant `zpool status` instead of `zfs status` (which isn't even a command); fixed.  I haven't dumped the output here, for brevity, as it's just an unremarkable listing of a simple root pool with no mention at all of the bad pool.